# Can a man marry his half sister's daughter?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, family

My half sister (from the same father but the same mother) has a daughter whom I would like to marry. Is she halal to me or haram

Comment: Among those who are prohibited to you according (4:23) are "... your sister's daughters" and there's no difference between a sister from the same mother or an other wife of your father! You couldn't even marry the daughter of your sister's daughters as they are prohibited by lineage.

Comment: Here two relevant Questions http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/what-women-cant-a-man-marry http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8943/what-kind-of-relations-are-explicitly-forbidden-in-islam-for-marriage

Comment: How's she your half sister if you have the same father and mother?

Comment: @Sayyid well i think the confusion is that non-Muslims may call them half sister or half brother while in Islam they are clearly considered as sister and brother unless they are bastards!

Answer (score 1):

NO you can not. Because a half sister (a sister with whom one has only one parent in common) is treated exactly as a (normal) sister in  this case ( in Islam). And I think this is commonly known among  the Muslim community.